# How to set a number as default in contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a number field on my contact form and i would like to set a number as default. Please anyone know how i can set a number as default.

Answer (score 3):

You can add default value in the tag which define the number input like this

```
[number number-780 "123"]
```

**"123"** is the default value.

Also you can use the build in tools to define the form.

[image]